# ruby gsub new line characters

Tags: ruby, regex, newline, gsub

I have a string with newline characters that I want to gsub out for white space.

```
"hello I\r\nam a test\r\n\r\nstring".gsub(/[\\r\\n]/, ' ')
```

something like this ^ only my regex seems to be replacing the `'r'` and `'n'` letters as well. the other constraint is sometimes the pattern repeats itself twice and thus would be replaced with two whitespaces in a row, although this is not preferable it is better than all the text being cut apart.

If there is a way to only select the new line characters. Or even better if there a more rubiestic way of approaching this outside of going to regex?

Comment: `gsub(/[\r\n]/, ' ')`?

Comment: Try [`.gsub(/[\r\n]+/, ' ')`](https://ideone.com/C79sey) if you want to replace whole chunks of `\r` and `\n` with 1 single space.

Comment: I tried that in http://rubular.com/ but i keep getting no results.

Comment: Tried both in IRB and they both work! Answer it and I will +1 your comments

Comment: `str.split.join(' ')` would also work but is more expensive due to the intermediate array.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: `tr("\r\n", ' ').squeeze(' ')`. I believe it’s the fastest way, but on simple strings the answer by @Stefan is much better.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have mixed consecutive line breaks that you want to replace with a single space, you may use the following regex solution:

```
s.gsub(/\R+/, ' ')
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/SE4pQc).

The `\R` matches any type of line break and `+` matches one or more occurrences  of the quantified subpattern.

Note that in case you have to deal with an older version of Ruby, you will need to use the *negated character class* `[\r\n]` that matches either `\r` or `\n`:

```
.gsub(/[\r\n]+/, ' ')
```

or - add all possible linebreaks:

```
/gsub(/(?:\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029])+/, ' ')
```

Comment: The point is that `\\` in your regex matches a literal ``\``, and `r` and `n` were matched as literal letters.

Comment: Wiktor, where did you find the `\R` shorthand? I can't find any reference anywhere for that in either the [Ruby docs][1] or on [regular-expressions.info][2]?

I don't think your example actually works, at least it doesn't in IRB for me. I think in the Ruby demo you linked it's not showing up because the HTML rendering is swallowing up the whitespace.

  [1]: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html
  [2]: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html

Comment: My first comment was corrupt, it was: The point is that ``\\`` in your regex matches a literal ``\``, and `r` and `n` were matched as literal letters.

Comment: Look: [*Main New features:
  Regular Expressions (depends on the syntax):
    `\K`, `\R`, `\X`, `(?(cond)yes|no)`
    `(?adlu)`, `\g{name}`, `\g{n}`, `(?&name)`, `(?n)`, `(?R)`, `(?0)`
    `(?P<name>...)`, `(?P=name)`, `(?P>name)`*](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for your test case:

`"hello I\r\nam a test\r\n\r\nstring".gsub(/[\r\n]/, ' ')`

If you don't want successive `\r\n` characters to result in duplicate spaces you can use this instead:

`"hello I\r\nam a test\r\n\r\nstring".gsub(/[\r\n]+/, ' ')`

(Note the addition of the `+` after the character class.)

As Wiktor mentioned, you're using `\\` in your regex, which inside the regex literal `/.../` actually escapes a backslash, meaning you're matching a literal backslash `\`, `r`, or `n` as part of your expression. Escaping characters works differently in regex literals, since `\` is used so much, it makes no sense to have a special escape for it (as opposed to regular strings, which is a whole different animal).